# How to get the address of a kernel module that was inserted using insmod?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I would like to know the address of a kernel module. Actually, from stack trace it looks that the crash has been triggered from a kernel module (which have been insmoded after system boots up). There are several modules I insmod manually. So I need to detect which module among these is triggering the crash. Please let me know how to get the address of each modules loaded using insmod.

Comment: I am using linux kernel 2.6.34.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cat /proc/modules` should give you a rough guide to where things are loaded. You might get more of a clue about exactly where the kernel crash is by looking at `/proc/kallsyms`.

Answer (score 4):

`/sys/module/<MODULE_NAME>/sections/` contains addresses of all sections of your module. Since most section begin with a dot (`.`), don't forget to pass `-a` to `ls` when listing this directory content:

```
$ ls -a /sys/module/usbcore/sections/
.                      __ex_table                 __param
..                     .fixup                     .rodata
.altinstr_replacement  .gnu.linkonce.this_module  .rodata.str1.1
.altinstructions       .init.text                 .rodata.str1.8
.bss                   __kcrctab_gpl              .smp_locks
__bug_table            __ksymtab_gpl              .strtab
.data                  __ksymtab_strings          .symtab
.data..read_mostly     __mcount_loc               .text
.data.unlikely         .note.gnu.build-id         .text.unlikely
.exit.text             .parainstructions          __verbose
```

Comment: Do you understand why the value of `.text` is something much smaller than the values shown by `/proc/modules` and `pr_debug` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836301/895245 (both the same, and correct according to QEMU + GDB)?

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功 Here, I find same values in `/proc/modules` and in `/sys/module/<MODULE_NAME>/sections/.text`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Here is a minimal reproducible example where I see the difference: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/bfba11afddae2f7b2c1335b4e23133e9cd3c9126#gdb-module_init-calculate-entry-address

Comment: @CiroSantilli I won't qualify your example "minimal". Are you sure you are not confused between output of `readelf` and files from `/sys`? `.text` address provided by `readelf` is much smaller since it is not yet relocated.

Comment: OK, minimal within bisecting 50 kernel configs :-) I am certain, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

**`pr_debug` on dmesg**

If we enable `pr_debug`, then it shows the base address the module was loaded at.

This can be useful for example if the module panics at `init_module` and you can't read `/proc/modules` interactively.

The best way to enable `pr_debug` is to compile the kernel with `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y` as explained at: [Why is pr_debug of the Linux kernel not giving any output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936199/why-is-pr-debug-of-the-linux-kernel-not-giving-any-output/49835405#49835405)

Then when you do:

```
echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
echo 'file kernel/module.c +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
insmod mymodule.ko
```

we see a line of form:

```
0xffffffffc0005000 .text
```

which contains the base address.

Comment: This is amazingly useful and might have helped me get to the bottom of a months-long bug-hunt. But how on earth do you derive these incantations?

Comment: @bodgesoc thanks! It's like any open source problem: a mixture of read the source/Google into it/notice by chance when you don't need it :-)