# Why is pr_debug of the Linux kernel not giving any output?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debugging

I have a loadable kernel module and its init is as given below

```
static int __init id_init(void)
{
    struct identity *temp;

    /* some code which is not relevant to the question */

    temp = identity_find(3);
    pr_debug("id 3 = %s\n", temp->name);

    temp = identity_find(42);
    if (temp == NULL)
        pr_debug("id 42 not found\n");

    /* some code which is not relevant to the question */

    return 0;
}
```

Also I have enabled dynamic debugging enabled on the kernel version I am using - i.e `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`.

And in the Makefile of the module I have added a line `CFLAGS_[id].o := -DDEBUG` where `id.c` is the file name.

Now I checked in the `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control` after doing insmod of this module, in which I found the below lines

```
/home/pauldc/Programming/Kernel/id/id.c:69 [id]id_init =_ "id 42 not found\012"
/home/pauldc/Programming/Kernel/id/id.c:65 [id]id_init =_ "id 3 = %s\012"
```

Even after doing all this, to my disappointment I could not find the above two pr_debug statements in the output of dmesg. So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Check your system's log level. May be its not supposed to print debug logs.

Comment: Have you not seem in dmesg or on screen or both? Try to add `dyndbg` parameter to the module when you load it. If you have compiled in use `<NAME>.dyndbg`, where <NAME> is a name of your module accordingly to Makefile.

Comment: @Miline Did you mean CONFIG_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT ? That is 4, as reported by the config file. But does that make any difference?

Comment: Any specific reason why you can not use printk?

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I did not get it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Miline I cannot use printk. This requirement comes from the assignment question.

Comment: First of all, remove -DDEBUG from your Makefile. It's often wrong approach. Enable DYNAMIC_DEBUG (like you did already). Compile everything, then if you have module you load and it's called `id`, do `modprobe id dyndbg`. Also, if you would like to see on screen, set loglevel to 8.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the `echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835405/895245

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add following to Makefile, assuming `filename.c` is the module source file.

```
CFLAGS_filename.o := -DDEBUG
```

not

```
CFLAGS_[filename].o := -DDEBUG
```

Refer https://www.kernel.org/doc/local/pr_debug.txt

Comment: Or, to enable debug for the whole module, you can modify the Makefile in that directory and add flags to ccflags-y, if I understand section 4.2 of this document properly: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Answer (score 9):

**`CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`**

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html

If you compile the kernel with this option, then you can do amazing things like:

```
echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
echo 'file kernel/module.c +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

and this will selectively enable the `pr_debug()` you want.

We can then test this out with:

```
insmod mymodule.ko
```

which prints a lot of extra debug info as in:

```
[   84.875592] init_module: umod=0000000073518b66, len=185416, uargs=000000009c6e375a                    
[   84.876099] Core section allocation order:       
[   84.876257]  .text                               
[   84.876332]  .note.gnu.build-id                  
[   84.876418]  .rodata.str1.1                      
[   84.876492]  .orc_unwind_ip                      
[   84.876568]  .orc_unwind                         
[   84.876636]  __mcount_loc                        
[   84.876705]  .data                               
[   84.876760]  .gnu.linkonce.this_module           
[   84.876856]  .bss                                
[   84.876919] Init section allocation order:       
[   84.877041]  .symtab                             
[   84.877121]  .strtab                             
[   84.877235] final section addresses:             
[   84.877352]  0xffffffffc0006000 .note.gnu.build-id                                                    
[   84.877482]  0xffffffffc0005000 .text            
[   84.877580]  0xffffffffc0006024 .rodata.str1.1   
[   84.877695]  0xffffffffc0006040 .orc_unwind_ip   
[   84.877805]  0xffffffffc0006050 .orc_unwind      
[   84.877905]  0xffffffffc0006068 __mcount_loc     
[   84.878012]  0xffffffffc0007000 .data            
[   84.878107]  0xffffffffc0007000 .gnu.linkonce.this_module                                             
[   84.878238]  0xffffffffc0007340 .bss             
[   84.878331]  0xffffffffc000a000 .symtab          
[   84.878430]  0xffffffffc000a348 .strtab          
[   84.878657] Absolute symbol: 0x00000000          
[   84.878951] Absolute symbol: 0x00000000          
[   84.879713] hello init
```

And in particular, it contains the [module load address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384605/how-to-get-the-address-of-a-kernel-module-that-was-using-insmod/49836301#49836301):

```
[   84.877482]  0xffffffffc0005000 .text
```

which is useful to convert addresses to lines.

For modules, we can do:

```
echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
echo 'module myprintk +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
insmod /myprintk.ko
```

which allows us to easily test `pr_debug` by adding that to our own module.

Tested on kernel 4.16 with [this setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f33dab4a1ca3c1f823392f64c78828f56f10f5f1#pr_debug).

**`printk(KERN_DEBUG` != `pr_debug` when `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`**

This is very inconsistent, but `printk(KERN_DEBUG` does show up when `loglevel=8` even if we don't enable `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`, this can be seen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37283021/895245

Comment: Where do the default log levels come from without dynamic being enabled? And can you dig somewhere for the remainder of the log messages (the ones of lower priority than the default log levels) or are they just not emitted altogether?

Comment: @sherrellbc I'm lazy to research now, but this should be easy to find out with some quick experiments/looking at the source, let me know if you do.