# How to get details of all modules / drivers that were initialized / probed during the Linux kernel boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, init

I need the sequence of modules/drivers that are invoked|initialized|probed during the kernl boot.

Can you please let me know if any flash command-line option available to get this sequence ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing the option "initcall_debug" on the kernel command line will cause timing information to be printed to the console for each init routine of built-in drivers. The initcalls are used to initialize statically linked kernel drivers and subsystems and contribute a significant amount of time to the Linux boot process. (Loadable modules are not available until after the root filesystem has been mounted.)

The output looks like:

```
calling  tty_class_init+0x0/0x44 @ 1
initcall tty_class_init+0x0/0x44 returned 0 after 9765 usecs
calling  spi_init+0x0/0x90 @ 1
initcall spi_init+0x0/0x90 returned 0 after 9765 usecs
```

Reference: http://elinux.org/Initcall_Debug

## Addendum

Specifying the kernel parameter "ignore_loglevel" along with the "initcall_debug" will ensure that the information will be displayed during boot.

Comment: After enabling both initcall_debug=1 and ignore_loglevel=1 on the kernel command line, I am able to see the module initialization start and end times. The below link has more details on this.

https://chengyihe.wordpress.com/2015/12/13/android-kernel-enable-initcall_debug-to-debug-initcall/

Comment: The assignment "=1" is not necessary for the "initcall_debug" parameter.  If you do not want to [change the log level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390004/change-default-console-loglevel-during-boot-up/16390389#16390389) on the console, then you can use the `dmesg | less` commands to review the boot messages (assuming the log buffer is large enough and booting is successful to get you a shell prompt).

Comment: Or `loglevel=8`. Arghh, very confusing how `pr_debug(` does not show but `printk(KERN_DEBUG` with `ignore_loglevel` and `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936199/why-is-pr-debug-of-the-linux-kernel-not-giving-any-output/49835405#49835405

Answer (score 0):

After enabling both initcall_debug=1 and ignore_loglevel=1 on the kernel command line, I am able to see the module initialization start and end times. The below link has more details on this.

https://chengyihe.wordpress.com/2015/12/13/android-kernel-enable-initcall_debug-to-debug-initcall/

Comment: Copying my answer for your own answer is tacky.  This site won't last very long if every questioner was like you.

Comment: Hi sir.. I don't have any wrong thoughts here actually. I found more detail explanation on that web page. So I thought it would be helpful here ans added as a new answer. But still I have given upvote to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for reconsidering your actions.