# adding a built in module to the kernel source, the module isn't loaded

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have programmed a simple module that can be loaded into the kernel to control a simple led. It works fine.
The source files are two C files and one header file:

```
gpio_handler_ws.c nct5104d_access.c nct5104d_access.h
```

I decided to add it to kernel sources doing these steps:

```
 1. In drivers/char modify the Kconfig file adding:

    config GPIO0_DEVICE
        tristate "GPIO0 device"
        default y
        help
            "Creates /dev/wsgpio0 char device to control GPIO0"

 2. In drivers/char modify the Makefile file adding:

       obj-$(CONFIG_GPIO0_DEVICE)   += wsgpio_udev.o
       wsgpio_udev-objs := gpio_handler_ws.o nct5104d_access.o

 3. Copy source and headers files to drivers/char directory
```

Then, if I select the m option in menuconfig to compile it as a module, it creates the wsgpio_udev.ko file that works as expected, I can load it and it creates de /dev/wsgpio0 device that controls the LED.

BUT if I select the built-in option it compiles and generates the wsgpio_udev.o file but after rebooting with the new kernel no /dev/wsgpio0 device is created. As far as I know, the built-in modules are listed in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin but I don't see wsgpio_udev.ko there

Am I missing something?

Comment: is the "triestate" typo in your kernel source, or just in this post?

Comment: Use 'lsmod' command to list loaded modules. or $cat /proc/modules to check your module is loaded into kernel.

Comment: @AlexZeffertt it was a typo in the post, I edited it

Comment: @beparas that just shows the loaded modules, not the ones that are built into the kernel

Comment: Looked for an example of what you want to do in drivers/char/Makefile and found this.  Note, they didn't use the -objs suffix:  obj-$(CONFIG_JS_RTC)  += js-rtc.o
js-rtc-y = rtc.o

Comment: @AlexZeffertt thanks Alex, I'll try it that way

Comment: *"generates the wsgpio_udev.o file but after rebooting with the new kernel no /dev/wsgpio0 device is created."* -- You need to do more debugging between those two steps.   Inspect **System.map** for the init entry point of your driver.  If your driver is in the kernel, then use `initcall_debug` parameter to check if your driver's init routine is called.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272109/how-to-get-details-of-all-modules-drivers-got-initialized-probed-during-kernel-b/37283021#37283021