# Boot of embedded Linux is stuck. How to debug?

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot, petalinux

In embedded platform built by petalinux, during boot(from u-boot), the last print I see is(sometimes) mmcblk0boot1 print.
What are the good ways to debug/trace/fix the problem?

As you can see at the end of the log is the start of another boot
The attached log

=======================================================================

```
> U-Boot 2015.07 (Jul 22 2018 - 14:04:29 +0300)
> DRAM:  ECC disabled 511 MiB
> MMC:   Max clock 26000000, Min clock 0
> zynq_sdhci: 0
> SF: Detected S25FL128S_64K with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB,   total 16 MiB
> *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment
> In:    serial
> Out:   serial
> Err:   serial
> Net:   Gem.e000b000
> U-BOOT for AAS_TOP_V0_00_12
> Hit any key to stop autoboot:  4  3  2  1  0 
> Device: zynq_sdhci
> Manufacturer ID: fe
> OEM: 14e
> Name: MMC04 
> Tran Speed: 26000000
> Rd Block Len: 512
> MMC version 4.4.1
> High Capacity: Yes
> Capacity: 3.5 GiB
> Bus Width: 4-bit
> Erase Group Size: 512 KiB
> HC WP Group Size: 4 MiB
> User Capacity: 3.5 GiB
> Boot Capacity: 16 MiB ENH
> RPMB Capacity: 128 KiB ENH
> reading image.ub
> 7775932 bytes read in 750 ms (9.9 MiB/s)
> ## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 01000000 ...
>    Using 'conf@1' configuration
>    Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
>    Trying 'kernel@1' kernel subimage
>      Description:  PetaLinux Kernel
>      Type:         Kernel Image
>      Compression:  gzip compressed
>      Data Start:   0x010000f0
>      Data Size:    7760664 Bytes = 7.4 MiB
>      Architecture: ARM
>      OS:           Linux
>      Load Address: 0x00008000
>      Entry Point:  0x00008000
>      Hash algo:    crc32
>      Hash value:   53e3bbd8
>    Verifying Hash Integrity ... crc32+ OK
> ## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 01000000 ...
>    Using 'conf@1' configuration
>    Trying 'fdt@1' fdt subimage
>      Description:  Flattened Device Tree blob
>      Type:         Flat Device Tree
>      Compression:  uncompressed
>      Data Start:   0x01766cec
>      Data Size:    13972 Bytes = 13.6 KiB
>      Architecture: ARM
>      Hash algo:    crc32
>      Hash value:   bdcc1805
>    Verifying Hash Integrity ... crc32+ OK
>    Booting using the fdt blob at 0x1766cec
>    Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
>    Loading Device Tree to 07ff9000, end 07fff693 ... OK
```

## Starting kernel:

```
> Starting kernel ...
> Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

> Linux version 4.0.0-xilinx (alex@ubuntu) (gcc version 4.9.2 
>  (SourceryCodeBench Lite 2015.05-17) ) #3 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 12 10:10:19 
> CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
> CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
> Machine model: MY_MACHINE
> bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled
> cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x1ec00000
> Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
> PERCPU: Embedded 11 pages/cpu @dfecf000 s12672 r8192 d24192 u45056
> Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129794
> Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200 earlyprintk
> PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
> Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
> Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
> Memory: 490876K/523264K available (4763K kernel code, 223K rwdata, 1708K
> rodata, 4376K init, 208K bss, 16004K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved, 0K  
>highmem)
> Virtual kernel memory layout:
>     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
>     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
>     vmalloc : 0xe0000000 - 0xff000000   ( 496 MB)
>     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdff00000   ( 511 MB)
>     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
>     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
>       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0659f7c   (6472 kB)
>       .init : 0xc065a000 - 0xc0aa0000   (4376 kB)
>       .data : 0xc0aa0000 - 0xc0ad7e60   ( 224 kB)
>        .bss : 0xc0ad7e60 - 0xc0b0c174   ( 209 kB)
> Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
>   Additional per-CPU info printed with stalls.
>   RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
> RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
> NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
> L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
> L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
> L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
> L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
> L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
> L2C-310 ID prefetch enabled, offset 1 lines
> L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
> L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
> L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x76760001
> slcr mapped to e0004000
> zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at e0004100
> Zynq clock init
> sched_clock: 64 bits at 333MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 3298534883328ns
> timer #0 at e0008000, irq=17
> Console: colour dummy device 80x30
> Calibrating delay loop... 1332.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=6660096)
> pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
> Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
> Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
> CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
> CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
> Setting up static identity map for 0x482348 - 0x4823a0
> CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
> Brought up 2 CPUs
> SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (2664.03 BogoMIPS).
> CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
> devtmpfs: initialized
> VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
> pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
> NET: Registered protocol family 16
> DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
> cpuidle: using governor ladder
> cpuidle: using governor menu
> hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
> hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
> zynq-ocm f800c000.ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0xe0080000
> vgaarb: loaded
> SCSI subsystem initialized
> usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
> usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
> usbcore: registered new device driver usb
> media: Linux media interface: v0.10
> Linux video capture interface: v2.00
> pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
> pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti 
>   <giometti@linux.it>
> PTP clock support registered
> EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
> Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
> Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
> NET: Registered protocol family 2
> TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
> TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
> TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
> TCP: reno registered
> UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
> UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
> NET: Registered protocol family 1
> RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
> RPC: Registered udp transport module.
> RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
> RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
> hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters 
>  available
> futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
> jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
> io scheduler noop registered
> io scheduler deadline registered
> io scheduler cfq registered (default)
> zynq-pinctrl 700.pinctrl: zynq pinctrl initialized
> dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
> dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac:  DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4   
>   Num_Events-16
> e0000000.serial: ttyPS1 at MMIO 0xe0000000 (irq = 144, base_baud = 3125000)
>  is a xuartps
> e0001000.serial: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 145, base_baud = 3125000) 
>  is a xuartps
> �console [ttyPS0] enabled
> console [ttyPS0] enabled
> bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
> bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
> xdevcfg f8007000.devcfg: ioremap 0xf8007000 to e006c000
> [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
> brd: module loaded
> loop: module loaded
> CAN device driver interface
> libphy: MACB_mii_bus: probed
> macb e000b000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00020118 at 0xe000b000 irq
>   149 (00:0a:35:00:1e:53)
> macb e000b000.ethernet eth0: attached PHY driver [Marvell 88E1510] 
>    (mii_bus:phy_addr=e000b000.etherne:00, irq=-1)
> e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
> e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2014 Intel Corporation.
> ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
> ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
> usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
> mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
> i2c /dev entries driver
> at24 0-0050: 1024 byte 24c08 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
> cdns-i2c e0004000.i2c: 400 kHz mmio e0004000 irq 141
> Xilinx Zynq CpuIdle Driver started
> Driver 'mmcblk' needs updating - please use bus_type methods
> sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
> sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
> sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
> sdhci-arasan e0101000.sdhci: No vmmc regulator found
> sdhci-arasan e0101000.sdhci: No vqmmc regulator found
> mmc0: SDHCI controller on e0101000.sdhci [e0101000.sdhci] using ADMA
> ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
> usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
> usbhid: USB HID core driver
> TCP: cubic registered
> NET: Registered protocol family 17
> can: controller area network core (rev 20120528 abi 9)
> NET: Registered protocol family 29
> can: raw protocol (rev 20120528)
> can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20120528 t)
> can: netlink gateway (rev 20130117) max_hops=1
> Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
> /home/alex/Petalinux/petalinux-v2015.4-final/components/linux-kernel/xlnx- 
>   4.0/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
> ALSA device list:
>   No soundcards found.
> Freeing unused kernel memory: 4376K (c065a000 - c0aa0000)
> mmc0: MAN_BKOPS_EN bit is not set
> mmc0: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
>  
> INIT: mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 MMC04G 3.52 GiB 
> mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 MMC04G partition 1 16.0 MiB
> mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 MMC04G partition 2 16.0 MiB

> U-Boot 2015.07 (Jul 22 2018 - 14:04:29 +0300)
```

Comment: First you have to understand what is the state of your system: Is it bootloader? If so, at which stage? Or is it OS? Which OS? Etc.

Comment: It's after second-stage BL. At least I've seen "Starting kernel ..." . It's "Linux version 4.0.0-xilinx"

Comment: *"At least I've seen "Starting kernel ..." ."* --That text is output by U-Boot, and simply means that execution has been transferred to the code that has been loaded into memory (i.e. you neglect to provide any details, a zImage perhaps?).  *"the last print I see is(sometimes) mmcblk0boot1 print. "* -- That makes no sense because it has no context.  Either provide an accurate description or post an actual boot log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get details of all modules / drivers that were initialized / probed during the Linux kernel boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272109/how-to-get-details-of-all-modules-drivers-that-were-initialized-probed-durin)

Comment: @sawdust Thank you. Attached the log to the original post.